# Explanation what for(i=0;1;i++) does in C?

Tags: c, string, for-loop, file-io

what `for (i=0;1;i++)` exactly does? when the `for loop` will terminate? after reaching value of `i=1`? When will that happen?
(looked for this type of loop in internet and Book C(how to program, Deitel&Deitel), without any result...)

```
    int i;
    for (i=0;1;i++)
        {
        // Some code starts
        // ...
        // Some code ends
        if (*Something Happens*)
            break;
        }
```

P.S. I simplified the original code for ease of understanding.

Comment: You `break` out of the loop. You could also write `int i = 0; while (1) { ... i++;}`

Comment: In loop: `for (i=0; 1; i++)` breaking condition is True. so it runs infinity. But because you uses `i` as index to `words[i]` you are calling Undefined behaviour

Comment: it's Infinite loop. Termination condition is `if (fgets(words[i],max_line_len-1,fp)==NULL)`

Comment: As always: `(char*)malloc(max_line_len);` should be `malloc(max_line_len);`, or better yet: `malloc(max_line_len*sizeof(words[i]));` _don't cast the pointer `malloc` returns_

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem, about the `(char*)malloc(max_line_len)`, is it the same for `words = (char **)realloc(words,sizeof(char*)*new_size);`, can the `(char **)` be excluded as well?

Comment: @MotherLand: Yes, it _should_ be, even: `words = realloc(words, sizeof(*words)*new_size);` is what it should read. as for my previous comment, I forgot to add a dereferencing `*` to `words[i]`, so you should add that there, too: `malloc(max_line_len*size(*(words[i])));`. Since you're assigning a pointer to a variable, you can safely assume that you can dereference that variable. Weather it be a pointer to a pointer, or a pointer to a struct, or primitive: `char **words`, then `sizeof(*words)` will yield the size of a char pointer, but `sizeof(*(words[i]))` will be sizeof char

Comment: It's the best way to ensure you're allocating the memory required for the type you're storing: simply use whatever the pointer is said to point to. Change `char **words` to `unsigned long **words` and the `malloc` calls will still work perfectly, without having to change casts and `sizeof`'s all over the place. It makes your code less error-prone overall.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem its error when i add the dereferencing `*` to `words[i]`, says could not find the output file (.o). it should be `malloc(max_line_len*sizeOF(*(words[i])))` am I right?

Comment: @MotherLand: it _should_ read `malloc(max_line_len*sizeof(*(words[i])));` and work just fine. [Check this codepad, for an example](http://codepad.org/FQDNjg2k). what's the exact error message you're getting? is it saying something about an implicit declaration?

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem if im using `malloc(max_line_len*size(*(words[i])));`, but `malloc(max_line_len*sizeof(*(words[i])));` works fine. I guess you just mistyped. :-)

Comment: @MotherLand: oh, just saw my typo. It should've been `sizeof`, of course. I thought you meant it didn't work when you used `sizeOF` (because of the upper-case `OF` bit)... when you were just pointing out my mistake...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since in C an `int` can be interpreted as a boolean using a zero/non-zero rule (zero means "false", anything else means "true") the loop is going to continue until a `break` statement is reached inside the loop's body.

You can rewrite the same loop as

```
for (i=0; ;i++)
```

because in the absence of a condition in the middle the loop is going to continue until a `break` as well.

Answer (score 6):

> what `for (i=0;1;i++)` exactly does?

```
 for (i=0;1;i++)
```

is an infinite loop because `1` (a non zero value) is evaluates to `true`, hence in this case the conditional expression of `for` will becomes always `true`.

> when the for loop will terminate?

The statement

```
 if (fgets(words[i],max_line_len-1,fp)==NULL)
        break;
```

will terminate the loop on condition being `true` in `if`.

> after reaching value of `i=1`?

No. I explained it above.

> When will that happen?

`i = 1` will happen on second iteration. But this will not terminate the loop.

Comment: ... because in `C` everything which is not `NULL`/`0` evaluates to true

Answer (score 2):

below snippets are exactly the same

```
for (i=0; 1; i++) {
    // some code
}


i = 0;
while (true) {
    // some code
    i++;
}
```

the code you written will terminated with the statement `break`, namely below code in your snippet

```
if (fgets(words[i],max_line_len-1,fp)==NULL)
    break; // this will jump out of the loop
```

Answer (score 1):

That's an infinite loop! You should use `break` with some condition to come out of loop.

Answer (score 1):

`for (i=0;1;i++)` is infinite loop, which equals to while(1) or while(true) in c++.
Since any non-zero variable will be interpreted as true for boolean variable in c. however

```
if (fgets(words[i],max_line_len-1,fp)==NULL)
            break;
```

will guarantee to exit the loop when read the end of the file.

`while (1)` or `for (i=0;1;i++)` is one style of loop, it must break inner the loop to make sure no infinite loop. I think one advantage of this style will make the format of `while` or `for` looks uniform.